# command createIndexes requires authentication

Tags: mongodb, jhipster

Getting following error
I have mongodb docker running on remote system. I am able to logon through mongo console and create index
While running mvnw I am getting following exception

The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command createIndexes requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized"}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command createIndexes requires authentication' on server xxxxxx:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command createIndexes requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized"}

I created user with all roles. Any help is appreciated

---

db.createUser(
{
user: "jhipster",
pwd: "jhipster",
roles: [ { role: "dbAdmin", db: "argumentationMap" } , { role: "readWrite", db: "argumentationMap" }  ,  { role: "dbAdmin", db: "argumentationMap" }  ,{role: "userAdmin" , db:"argumentationMap"} ]
}
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

In my application.yml file :

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: dbname
      username: dbuser
      password: userpassword
      authentication-database: dbname
      host: yourIpaddrr
      port: 27017
```

in my pom.xml file I change

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mongobee</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongobee</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.dalet-oss</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongobee</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope it could help someone